# JAVA_HOME and java -version

Tags: java, version, environment-variables, java-home

I'm using a Windows .bat script and I set `JAVA_HOME` as `C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_32`
when I do a `java -version`, it still shows the 1.3

How can I fix this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It doesn't give any error btw

Comment: Show output of `echo %PATH%`.

Comment: That isn't enough. Prepend `JAVA_HOME\bin` to `PATH`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try `%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -version`

If you modify `JAVA_HOME`, it's usually better to invoke `java` with an absolute path (using `JAVA_HOME`) because the new binary is probably not in the path (and then Windows will load the wrong binary).

Answer (score 18):

For me the issue was in my PATH variable, `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;` was added by java windows install before my `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;`.
So I'd `echo %JAVA_HOME%` pointing to a JDK7 and `java -version` showing jdk8.

I'd to put `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;` before `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;` so that `java -version` displays jdk7.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that the `PATH` environment variable is pointing to `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure not to mix the system variable path and the user variable system path. I feel OK in calling `java` without the absolute path (when I know how `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` are configured).

Answer (score 0):

Calling `java -version` from command line, causes cmd.exe to do the lookup on the "known" directories. "Known" means PATH environment variable. It seems that your PATH contains a java 1.3 `bin` folder, and not 1.6.

JAVA_HOME is another variable, that is used (for example, and not only) by java wrappers, or by scripts executing some java stuff.

Try doing this:

```
SET JAVA_HOME=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_32
%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java -version
```

Add quotes where needed.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue,in my case , I had two versions java installed. it can be fixed by uninstalling one version of java completely from system.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar scenario today - two Windows 10 devices - both have JRE 1.6 & 1.7.

When typing

```
 Java -version
```

One device shows 1.6 the other 1.7.

This was preventing me running a third party JAR to install some software on the device showing 1.6 (which worked fine on the device showing 1.7 when running java -version), using:

```
  java -jar ThirdParty.jar
```

As the JAR needed to be run by 1.7.

Cause of this was in the PATH environment variable - one device had the location of 1.6 first in the PATH list, moving the 1.7 location above the 1.6 location resulted in consistency using Java -version and allowed me to install the software.

Answer (score 0):

`java -version` will consult the paths in the *special* environment variable **Path**. You need to select the java version you want and move it upwards the latter (click "Move Up"). You probably have that reference to JDK 1.3 in **Path** above your addition of JDK 1.6. Since that's the first thing the OS finds, that's what it chooses to run.

Executing the command again with the same window opened after changing the environment variables will not work. Re-open it

I know this question is old but this was my case and I wanted to re-explain further, similar to @DanBot 's case